# cd to the most recently created directory

Tags: find, directory

I have a directory in which a number of directories are created daily. I want to enter into the directory which is created recently whose name starts with `cy`.

1. How can I find this directory?
2. Could I use `find` for this?

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: @ Gnouc `cy12_1234`,`sum_abc`etc., these type of directories are created in parent directory. I want to find recently created directory which starts with `cy`

Comment: Is there only one directory which name starts with `cy` or many? You should give your questoin more details so everybody can help you.

Comment: @ Gnouc No, there will be so many directories starts with `cy` since it is daily process.

Comment: @l0b0 Not at all! In that question, the newest file is determined from the file name.

Comment: Most unices don't track the date when a directory was created. Are there other ways you could tell which directory interests you, for example based on files that should be in that directory?

Comment: @  Gilles In all directories same name of files available daily with different data. I need the files which created in recent directory whose name starts with `cy`

Comment: I think cd $(ls cy* -t | head -n 1) should work

Answer (score 2):

In `Linux`, you can't get the created date of file. `ctime` is not created date. It changes when your file is updated content or metadata.

In `Mac OSX`, you can use option `-U`:

```
ls -tU
```

So you can try:

```
cd $(ls -tU parent/cv* | head -n 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to [find the latest file/directory](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003), depending on which tools you have at your disposal and how portable you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

There is no really good way to tell from a system perspective which is the last created directory, as as been pointed out ctime and mtime are not reliable indicators.  You could procedurally do this, by creating a file called .create-time when you create your directory and then never modify or change the permission on this file and use the file as your guide in selection.